# Potential jQuery initialization issue according to browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to practice my jQuery skills (beginner dev) and encountering an issue when I go to see my basic To Do List app deployed on GitHub.  It renders fine, but when I go to actually submit a new task to the list it seems to be the choke point.  My console says my line 95 in my code is my 'issue', and my line 95 is where I start my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

I based this off a tutorial I found on YouTube (potential mistake?) and it also seems to dislike my import of Fontawesome.  Here's my whole file:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.css">
  <style media="screen">
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      font-family: verdana;
      text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    body {
      min-height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0 50%, #333 50%);
    }

    .container {
      height: 450px;
      width: 330px;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      padding: 10px;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    #input {
      height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: #666;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 0 10px;
      margin: 15px 0;
    }

    #input::placeholder {
      color: #bbb;
    }

    ul li {
      background: #eee;
      color: #333;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      margin: 10px 0;
      padding: 10px;
      position: relative;
    }

    ul .fa-check,
    .fa-trash {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    ul .fa-check {
      right: 40px;
      color: green;
    }

    ul .fa-trash {
      right: 15px;
      color: #ff0033;
    }

    ul .checked {
      background: blue;
      text-decoration: line-through;
      transition: .2s;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="press enter to add text">
    <ul>
      <p>Here's what you have to do.</p>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#input').change(function() {
        var input = $(this).val();
        $('ul').append('<li>' + input + ' <i class="fas fa-check"></> <i class="fas fa-trash"></> </>');
        $(this).val('');
      });
      $('ul').on('click', '.fa-trash', function() {
        $(this).parent('li').fadeOut(200);
      });
      $('ul').on('click', '.fa-check', function() {
        $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('checked');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone has any thoughts on why it's saying my jQuery is 'not defined' I would really appreciate it!!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: ```(index):95 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):95

Comment: You have to include jquery, you can copy it out of the snippet `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` add this to your html file

Comment: THANK YOU! That was driving me nuts - I guess I misinterpreted the script src=jquery.js as including it so I appreciate that guidance! :)

Comment: That should include it. Maybe you didn't copy jquery.js to the server?